# AJAX manda informações para o PHP mas falha em fazer o INSERT só de um dado

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Veja esse meu código:

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/criaEvento.js"></script>
<form method="post">
<table width="420" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>Nome</td>
        <td colspan="3"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="nomeEvento" placeholder="exemplo: Festa no ap" size="30"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="10"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Detalhes
        <td colspan="3"><textarea class="form-control" name="maisInfos" placeholder="informais adicionais" rows="3" cols="33"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="10"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Onde</td>
        <td colspan="3"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="onde" placeholder="local" size="30"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="10"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Quando</td>
        <td><input id="dia" type="date" name="dia"></td>
        <td>Horário</td>
        <td><input id="hora" type="time" name="hora"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="10"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" id="salvar" name="salvar" value="SALVAR"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
(document).ready( function(){

    $("#salvar").click( function(){

        var dataString = $("form").serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'php/evento.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: 'data='+dataString,

            success: function(data){

            }

        });

    });
})
```

PHP:

```
<?php
include_once 'con.php';

$nomeEvento = $_POST['nomeEvento'];
$maisInfos = $_POST['maisInfos'];
$onde = $_POST['onde'];
$dia = $_POST['dia'];
$hora = $_POST['hora'];

$qryInsert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO evento VALUES(NULL, '$nomeEvento', '$maisInfos', '$onde', '$dia', '$hora')");
```

Ele passa os dados para o PHP mas no INSERT para o BD, só um dos dados é que NÃO é salvo, o resto vai...

Comment: Sem saber exatamente o que não está funcionando vai ficar difícil de te ajudar.

Comment: @André, todos os dados: maisInfos, onde, dia e hora, estão sendo salvos no BD, menos o nomeEvento.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que você está enviando os parâmetros de forma incorreta na chamada ajax.

```
data: 'data='+dataString,
```

Nessa linha você acaba gerando um novo dado chamado `data` onde o valor acaba sendo `data=nomeEvento=[valor preenchido]`, ou seja, o seu primeiro item em `dataString` acaba virando o valor de `data` e é perdido.

A função `.serialize()` já gera tudo que você precisa para enviar os dados via POST. Você só precisa fazer assim:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'php/evento.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: dataString, // passa diretamente a string contendo os dados do post

    success: function(data){

    }
});
```

Comment: É verdade André!

Comment: Valeu...
Outra coisa, como se formata códigos para serem exibidos aqui?
Já deu uma olhada na "documentação" de ajuda, aqui, mas não entendi

Comment: @GustavoSevero É só selecionar o seu código e clicar no botão `{}` na barra de ferramentas acima do editor.

Comment: Valeu André! Muito obrigado.